# AWS - custom deny message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, aws-sdk, policy

Sometime AWS policies evaluate to an authorization deny message, however, our employees don't always understand the reason why. In that cases, displaying a custom message would help a lot.

For example, I have a policy for technical support users which gives them the ability to attach policies to other users, except policies that allow the users to act on EC2 production instances. What I want to do is to display a message like "Assigning permissions to operate upon EC2 instances is not allowed, please contact XXX if you need to do that anyway".

Is that possible?

Comment: At the risk of coming across as somewhat elitist -- for which I apologize in advance, because it is not my intention -- it seems like a fair question... if a user is not able to understand or troubleshoot why a policy is not acceptable, then is it safe for that user to be in a position of manipulating permissions?  Presumably you are not allowing them to actually *write* policies, but only to attach existing ones.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot policies can be very, very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to customize error messages.

Plus, the error message is encrypted to prevent information about policies leaking (because this knowledge could be used to bypass security). Authorized persons can decrypt it to try and debug the cause but, as you say, the policies can be very, very complicated.